# Does HTML conform to the XML specification?

Tags: html, xml, specifications

HTML and XML are syntactically very similar, so what I want to know is if valid HTML code will always conform to the XML specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't.

HTML 2 through 4.x were SGML applications, not XML applications. (HTML+ might also have been an SGML application, it isn't clear from a brief skim of the specification)

HTML 5 has its own parse rules.

(XHTML and the XML serialisation of HTML 5 will be XML though)

Answer (score 2):

> Does HTML conform to the XML specification?

No, it does not. HTML supports:

- unclosed tags (e.g. `<img>` instead of `<img />`)
- wrongly nested tags (e.g. `<b><i>bla</b></i>` instead of `<b><i>bla</i></b>`)
- unquoted attributes (e.g. `<a name=foo>...</a>`)
- contents that is not propery encoded (e.g. `<em>this & that</em>` instead of `<em>this &amp; that</em>`)
- tags that explicitly must contain unencoded content (i.e. `<script>`)
- named entities (e.g. `&copy;` instead of `&#169;`)

The standard does not explicitly *allow* all of these notions, but all HTML parsers understand and support them.

None of them is legal in XML.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is more lenient. For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>foo</title>
bar
```

is a valid HTML5 document, but it's obviously not valid XML, since XML requires a top-level element that encompasses the whole document.

However, you can use one of the [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) languages, which are applications of XML with the same semantics as the corresponding HTML standards.